# Decomposition of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

**My question** : Given a polynomial
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}x^{n} $$
cannot be solved in general, but depending on the coefficients, can we know if it can be decomposed as a product of smaller order polynomials of degree 1 ,2 ,3 and 4 so in this case can be factorized and solved?

Answer (score 0):

By the [*fundamental theorem of algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) we know that every non-zero $n^\text{th}$ degree polynomial with constant complex coefficients has, counted with their algebraic multiplicity, *exactly* $n$ roots.

So by this means we can decompose, in the complex field, every polynomial into a product of polynomials with degree less than $n$. As an example take a $5^\text{th}$ degree polynomial $P(x)$ with three roots $x_1, x_2, x_3$ such that $$\text{a.m.}(x_1) = 1 \;\; \text{a.m.}(x_2) = 2\;\; \text{a.m.}(x_3) = 2$$ were $\text{a.m.}(x_n)$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $x_n$, then we can write $$P(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)^2(x-x_3)^2$$

Depending on the coefficients you can say something about the roots of the polynomial by using [*Decartes' rule of signs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) or with the [*Routh-Hurwitz critetion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion). I don't think that, in a general case, you can say anything more than this, but I stand to be corrected. Surely we can say something more by knowing the *form* of the polynomial